# How to get initial English word for utf8 string of multiple languages?

Tags: php, utf-8, cpu-word, icu

How to get initial English word for utf8 string of multiple languages for comparison purposes?

For instance, Chinese word, initial English word of "你" (means, you) is "n"; initial of "好"(means, good) is "h".

I know ICU could do this job but I want the PHP implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know ICU could do this job. But I want the PHP implementation.

You asked for it: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/intro.intl.php

Comment: use the Transliterator interface, something like "Han-Latin" which will turn "中国" into "zhōng guó".